# Logo becomes big on Mobile (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble. If you view this site on mobile or resize browser to phone size, scroll down, then scroll all the way back up, the logo becomes very big. I need it small like in the beginning (refresh page):
http://www.baycrest.org/birdie4baycrest/

I do have CSS break points, but I am using JS due to something specific. Here is my JS Code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() == 0) {        
        $('.logo').attr('src', '/birdie4baycrest/images/logobig3.jpg');
        $('.logo').width(203);
        $('.logo').height(293);
     } else {

        $('.logo').attr('src', '/birdie4baycrest/images/logobig.jpg');
        $('.logo').width(108);
        $('.logo').height(70);
     }
});
```

Comment: give it in % so then it will adjust

Comment: Something like a conditional based on the size of the browser would do --- `if( $(window).width() < 600px ){ $('.logo').width(108); }` (change the width in the IF condition from 600 to whatever value matches your breakpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution based on my earlier comment. Tested and working on your site in the Chrome Inspector.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() == 0) {

        $('.logo').attr('src', '/birdie4baycrest/images/logobig3.jpg');

        if( $(window).width() < 768 ){
            // logo loads at small size with a width of 104 and height of 150
            $('.logo').width(104);
            $('.logo').height(150);
        } else {
            // this is what the default is for large sizes
            $('.logo').width(203);
            $('.logo').height(293);
        }

    } else {

        $('.logo').attr('src', '/birdie4baycrest/images/logobig.jpg');
        $('.logo').width(108);
        $('.logo').height(70);

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much William! It worked perfectly. I understand what you did too, perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into bootstrap it gives you the ability to easily create responsive webpage designs [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp)  is a to get you on the right track.

Comment: The site is built with Bootstrap